# What percentage of the population of Ukraine support the war?

Tags: armed-conflict, ukraine, public-opinion

Ukrainian men between 18 and 60 cannot leave the country and have to defend themself against Russian aggression.

Are there any reliable numbers as to how much of the population actually supports the war effort vs. just giving up?

I have read [this](https://www.voanews.com/a/poll-shows-ukrainians-resolved-to-fight-until-victory/6796951.html) article claiming that 70% of Ukrainians support fighting until the end. Is this number reliable? Are there any other estimates? Is there a trend between east and west of Ukraine?

It seems difficult number to come by since every site has its interests. What is the most reliable estimate?

Comment: "most reliable" is going to be mainly opinion based. The Q is otherwise mostly a duplicate of https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/77335/how-can-we-estimate-the-real-support-of-continued-resistance-among-ukrainian-cit/

Comment: "just giving up" probably considerably less than those in favor of a negotiated peace along the current lines for example. The war is not going so bad that "just giving up" is the most favorable alternative.

Comment: The linked article doesn't say "until the end." It say they support fighting "until victory."  This question's wording plants a suggestion that a victory is impossible.  It should be closed as a push question regardless of whether it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the [Gallup article](https://news.gallup.com/poll/403133/ukrainians-support-fighting-until-victory.aspx) that is the basis for the Voice of America article the OP quoted. That supports the 70% overall proportion on favour of continuing the war, and breaks down the responses in several ways:

- Men (76%) are more in favour of continuing than women (64%).
- The highly educated (80%) are more in favour than the less-educated (68%).
- Inhabitants of eastern (56%) and southern (58%) Ukraine are less in favour than inhabitants of other parts of the country. This is not surprising: almost all the fighting has been in those regions, and many people will just want it to stop. Those regions also have higher proportions of Russian-speakers. The map is misleading: I seriously doubt Gallup was able to take polls in the Russian-controlled areas of Crimea, Donetsk and Luhansk.
- 91% agree that victory for the Ukrainians would require recovering all the territories where they have lost control since 2014: Crimea, Donetsk and Luhansk.

Gallup have motivation to produce an honest answer, since they operate world-wide, and opinion polling is their business. If they are regarded as untrustworthy, their business will suffer. Their numbers are also *plausible*: the variations by region, gender and education all have obvious explanations.

Their work may nonetheless have biases: as I said above, I expect they were only able to poll Ukrainian-controlled territory. There will also be a margin of error, due to the limitations of random sampling. That's likely to be 2-3%.